# Flexslider - Responsive css bug

Tags: jquery, css, slider, responsive-design, flexslider

I am trying to add responsive media queries to a theme and the Flexslider is doing this weird thing where it resizes based on the media query but only shows half of the image.

Here is a demo of this happening: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/framework/

Here is the css I used in the media query:

```
/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 980 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

    div#site_wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    div#site_wrap, div.footer, div.copyright, div#title {
        width:95%;
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
    }
    div.header, div.main, #container {
        width:auto;
    }
    .footer_form textarea {
        width:90%;
    }
}
```

Any idea what is causing this?  I have been at it all night.

** I forgot to mention, to see what I mean try resizing the browser until it gets below 980px wide.  The range from 768-980px is responsive so far, the rest of the theme shrinks but the image in the slider only displays the left half of the image while shrinking.

Comment: what exactly is the problem. On normal screen it looks ok, if I shrink my browser window, I can only see part of the slider.

Comment: Sorry, check edit in op.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your  **div.flex-viewport**. All other elements seem to size up correcty. This div however is stuck at 433px on my screen and I have no idea why or where it's set (at least I can't find anything in Firebug).

I checked my current Flexslider. I'm not using pos:rel on the element but the rest is the same and it scales nicely from 1200-200px.

Sorry to not have any more info. If I stumble upon it, I will post.

Comment: I didn't set this in css though.  I'm using the same code as the demo and it works fine there.  With overflow showing it displays all slides side by side.  Also, there is no css setting the div to be half width like that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Once it got too small the search bar was being bumped down out of the navigation area and falling into the slider.